# jQuery: randomize words in a string?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to randomize the words in a string using jquery but my code doesn't return anything.

This is what I have so far:

```
function makerand() {


  var text = "";
  var possible = "david, sarah, michelle, pedro";

   text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;

  alert(text);
}
```

**html:**

```
<button onclick="makerand()">click me</button>
```

what I need to do is to randomize that string like so for example:

```
sarah, pedro, michelle, david
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Comment: Do you want to change order of words in string?

Comment: @Mohammad, yes. that is correct.

Comment: @Mohammad Read the full question ?

Comment: Given duplicate shuffles the array and not the given String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the String by comma. You get an array back and then sort the array by giving random.

```js
var possible = "david, sarah, michelle, pedro";

var result = possible.split(", ").sort(function() {
    return 0.4 - Math.random()
}).join(", ");

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is changing order to specific order that @DavidHope incorectly said *randomize*.

Comment: @Mohammad OP himself accepted that , this is what OP need.

Comment: I know this. I mean @DavidHope does't write his need in question exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into an array like so:

`var items = possible.split(", ");`

Then shuffle the array like so: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Then rejoin the elements:

`possible.join(", ")`